# Ajax Post Different Data using a function or array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Actually I'm looking for a better way to submit data using ajax to php for multiple users. Please look at my code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#all").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('babon').click();
    document.getElementById('af').click();
    document.getElementById('anik').click();
    document.getElementById('abir').click();
    document.getElementById('aurko').click();
  });

  $("#babon").click(function(){
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    $('span.babon').text("Sending..");
    $.post("redeem.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           {"redeemcode":code,"gameid":"4548211","vcode":"87856"},
           function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
      var result = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
      $('span.babon').text(result.message);
    });
  });

  $("#anik").click(function(){
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    $('span.anik').text("Sending..");
    $.post("redeem.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           {"redeemcode":code,"gameid":"54489231","vcode":"56465"},
           function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
      var result = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
      $('span.anik').text(result.message);
    });
  });

  $("#abir").click(function(){
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    $('span.abir').text("Sending..");
    $.post("redeem.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           {"redeemcode":code,"gameid":"8798456","vcode":"78542"},
           function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
      var result = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
      $('span.abir').text(result.message);
    });
  });

  $("#aurko").click(function(){
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    $('span.aurko').text("Sending..");
    $.post("redeem.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           {"redeemcode":code,"gameid":"548745612","vcode":"24875"},
           function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
      var result = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
      $('span.aurko').text(result.message);
    });
  });

  $("#af").click(function(){
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    $('span.af').text("Sending..");
    $.post("redeem.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           {"redeemcode":code,"gameid":"9887254","vcode":"82499"},
           function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
      var result = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
      $('span.af').text(result.message);
    });
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRNLQO

See the output here in screenshot..
[image]

I use different ajax function to submit data to php. is there any way to submit data from a array? so code will look like more shorter and beautiful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a reusable function:

```
var sendingfunction = function(selector, gameid, vcode){
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    $('span.'+selector).text("Sending..");
    $.post("redeem.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           {"redeemcode":code,"gameid":gameid,"vcode":vcode},
           function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
               var result = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
               $('span.'+selector).text(result.message);
    });
}

$("#anik").click(function(){
    sendingfunction('anik', "54489231", "56465");
  });

$("#abir").click(function(){
    sendingfunction('abir', "54489231", "56465");
  });
...etc.
```

Comment: I got " **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (** " error for this `var sendingfunction(selector, gameid, vcode){`

Comment: I think it a function not variable.. so it will be `function sendingfunction(selector, gameid, vcode){`

Answer (score 1):

```
function callPostAjax(element, code, gameId, vCode) {
    $(element).text("Sending..");
    $.post("redeem.php", //Required URL of the page on server
         { "redeemcode": code, "gameid": gameId, "vcode": vCode },
         function (response, status) { // Required Callback Function
             var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
             $(element).text(result.message)
         }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
             $(element).text('error');
             console.error(error);
         });
}
$("#babon").click(function () {
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    callPostAjax('span.babon', code, "4548211", "87856");
});

$("#anik").click(function () {
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    callPostAjax('span.anik', code, "54489231", "56465");
});

$("#abir").click(function () {
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    callPostAjax('span.abir', code, "8798456", "78542");
});

$("#aurko").click(function () {
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    callPostAjax('span.aurko', code, "548745612", "24875");
});

$("#af").click(function () {
    var code = $('#rcode').val();
    callPostAjax('span.af', code, "9887254", "82499");
});
```

Comment: love your code too :) but next one is more shorter :) Thank you sir.

Comment: i agree with you,@Liam has more Experience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first consider if the `redeem.php` supports multiple records. If yes, give all of the same 'class' records and iterate over all the form elements using the `.each()` keyword and populate your request data before submitting.

Comment: ```.each()``` is  method of jquery